# Accessing openfire on a remote server

Tags: openfire

I set up openfire on a remote server by building the source. It works locally on the server, as ssh-ing into it and `wget 127.0.0.1:9090` both work. However, I am not able to access the admin console externally, i.e. `http://domainname:9090` doesn't load. What do I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons why this won't work. Does openfire actually bind to the IP address that *domainname* resolves to? What happens if you do (on the server itself)

```
wget http://1.2.3.4:9090
```

where 1.2.3.4 is your public IP address?
Is there a firewall? Has the DNS for *domainname* be configured and is working correctly?

Comment: i have installed openfire on my PC, if i do `192.168.1.111:9090` i can access it but not remotely with my public ip, i have forwarded the ports and checked it thru `http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/` that the port `9090` is open, disabled all the firewalls, but still cannot get it to access